# On the aspects of Normal Subgroups

Tags: group-theory

Given a normal subgroup $N$ in the finite group $G$
such that $i_G(N)$ and $o(N)$ are relatively prime, I want to
show that any element in $G$ such that $x^{o(N)} = e$ must be
in $N$. This is a problem that I am having issues finding
implications on.

I understand that given $x \in G$ such that
$x^{o(N)} = e$, $o(x) | o(N)$ based on the order of an element.
However, I could use some help on where to move from here.

Comment: Hint: If $x \not \in N$, then $xN$ is a non-identity element of $G/N$, so its order divides $i_{G}(N)$. On the other hand, we have $(xN)^{o(N)} = eN$, the identity of $G/N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Consider the element $xN$ in the quotient group $G/N$. On the one hand $$(xN)^{o(N)}=x^{o(N)}N=N\;.$$ On the other hand, what do you know about the order of $xN$ in $G/N$?